# Are site recommendations allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I need to learn PHP fundamentals, and so I'd like to put out a question on Software Recommendations asking "What site offers good, informative PHP tutorials?"

I'm not sure if site recommendations are within SR's scope, and haven't found information in the Help Center or Meta either way.

Comment: Related: [Can I ask for recommended websites?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/191/60)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, site recommendations are definitely **not** in scope.

However, there is an Area 51 proposal to make a tutorials site. It is currently in definition, so it needs some love (I.e. upvoting of questions that people feel are on topic). So why don't you [head on over there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58925/tutorials?referrer=pxdDyol4gV0RQ-1RmaknLw2) and take a look, and help get more questions voted up to 10.

Comment: I have done so. I wonder why they've limited the scope to technology tutorials; many other fields could use tutorial recommendations. Anyway, thanks for the link and the information.